# How to make the time displayed in 24 hour time format?

Tags: angular

How to make the time displayed in 24 hour time format? At the moment, my time is displayed in 12 hour format. How can this be fixed, and at the same time not greatly change my installed format?

```
date:'d/MM/yyyy h:mm'
```

Comment: use `H` instead of `h`.

Comment: Check out the doc for more date format options: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Comments above are 100% correct. Just adding some stuff: If you want to do more complex things regarding dates you can use moment js library, it's very powerful and reliable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For 24Hr format, you need to use `H` instead of `h`.

your filter should be `date:'d/MM/yyyy H:mm'`

You can find more option for date filter from [offical doc.](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

[see this example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rd4sjw)